# Can git help me merge changes during a application upgrade

Tags: git, configuration, merge

I now and then do software upgrades (Atlassian software, jira, confluence etc) for our customers. A problem I encounter every time is that the customer might have done some customization to the installed version (config changes, changed web templates etc) that should be handled (preserve or ignore). I don't know exactly what files where changed and I need to be sure not to miss anything. My solution so far has been to extract the install tar.gz of the installed version and use rsync (with --verbose --dry-run --itemize-changes) to identify what has changed. I then do some grep and sed magic to filter out the interesting parts, and apply the detected changes "manually".

So basically I have three directories; A (Old-version-with-changes), B (Old-version-clean) and C (New-version). I like to identify the changes in i A compared with B and optionally apply them to C.

Now, could I use git to aid me in this process? I particularly don't like the manually application of changes part. I'm fairly new to git, could someone point me in the right direction or tell me why this is an awful idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A traditional way of doing this is with `diff` and `patch`.  Everybody knows `diff`--it compares files and prints their differences.  You can use it with whole directories too.  But not everyone knows that you can take the output of `diff` (in the right mode) and feed it to `patch -p1` or similar and have it make the changes specified in the diff file (commonly named `*.patch`).

If you know which version of the tool was installed to start with, just unzip a fresh copy of it in a temporary directory, then diff that against the working copy.  That will give you a patch file (which you can surely store in source control!).  That file can then be applied ("ported") to other installed instances, including other versions so long as there's no merge conflict.  You'll be notified if there is a conflict, and can then fix it by hand.

Incidentally, this is how Linux packaging works sometimes--distributors take upstream sources and their own patch files and weave them together at build/packaging time.